# z-index not working in this page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://rb.alayadi.ae/

at the bottom of this page the black box i would like it to be position like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrSM3.jpg)

Please tell quick fix for this have tried this

```
#responsive_single_image_description {
position: absolute;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
color: white;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 4px;
text-align: right;
max-width: 90%;
left: -14px;
```

but somehow its being hidden and z-index not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your main style is loading last
2. add in your css in the element you want to override

   z-index: 9999 !important;
   position: relative ;

> position relative is important when using z-index